# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.Metadata.FrameworkElementMetadata' threw an exception

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm getting **The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.Metadata.FrameworkElementMetadata' threw an exception.** error at design time for a project.

Beside this here are two diffrent project's App.xaml files snapshot.Both of them uses same resources. One of them says key parameter cannot be null. And any of designer window cannot be open. All I see is the error I mentioned before.

Note: I'm using SL5 and also SL 5.0 interaction dll. I also aware of [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/669751/the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-expression-platform-silverlight-silverlightcommondesigntimeproperties-threw-an-exception).

I'm looking for any suggestion.

[image: This project also run at runtime]

[image: This project runs on design and runtime]

Comment: i would try taking the xmlns in and out. I've had similar problems where the telerik reference have caused me problems.

Comment: thank you. I got you. Maybe telerik,microsoft or we code same class so ambiguous references appear ? why not? I'll try.